# How to prevent tiring forearms when doing bicep curls

Tags: muscle-soreness, upper-body-workout, biceps, forearm, curls

I'm trying to focus more on building my biceps (biceps brachii) on specific days (I'm not doing it every day; I work on different muscle groups or just rest on other days).

However, I noticed that when I do standing bicep curls with my dumbbells—I use both simultaneously—my forearms (medial antebrachial) tire out before I can really feel as though I'm working out my biceps.

I'm looking for different exercises or techniques to build the biceps brachii wherein I would not be tiring out the forearms as much—that is, such that they would not tire out before I have sufficiently 'worked out' my biceps. If anyone has any recommendations, that would be great!

When doing my own research online, I've come across ones that need me to buy some sort of workout chair (preacher chair, incline chair, etc), but I want to be able to do them exclusively using my dumbbells at home.

If this is the wrong place to be posting this, please let me know and direct me to where it should be posted. Thank you so much for your time, everyone!

Comment: What does your form look like? Are you flexing at your wrist joints?

Comment: @JustSnilloc I'm just doing a normal bicep curl (in the following form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biceps_curl).... I don't really pay attention to my wrists, but I'd assume due to the weight of the dumbbell, my wrist are under some pressure and may be subconsciously be flexed/tensed

Answer (score 1):

One possible source of the problem would be the mechanics of the three primary muscles involved in elbow flexion: the single-joint [brachialis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachialis_muscle) and [brachioradialis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachioradialis) muscles, and the multi-joint [biceps brachii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biceps). Since both heads of the biceps brachii attach to the scapula—at the [coracoid process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coracoid_process) and [supraglenoid tubericle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supraglenoid_tubercle) for the short and long head, respectively—the position of the shoulder changes the length of the two muscle groups, and hence the degree and manner of activation involved in the performance of the curl.

We cannot [isolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_training#Isolation_exercises_versus_compound_exercises) any of the muscle groups, but we can alter their degree and manner of activation by flexing or extending the shoulder (lifting or dropping the elbow relative to the front of the body). Simultaneous flexion of the shoulder and elbow results in a near-[isometric contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_contraction) of the biceps brachii, theoretically affording it greater strength. This could consequently allow a greater lift while placing a relatively high load on the other muscles in the chain. Swinging the load flexes the shoulder, and this can cause the brachialis to fatigue early. (Note that the [medial antebrachial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_cutaneous_nerve_of_forearm) is the nerve, not the muscle.) In order to maximise activation of the biceps brachii, the elbow must be *fixed* at the side of the body or behind it. Performing curls from a reclined position is one method of achieving this posture, which pre-stretches the biceps brachii.

The other possibility is excessive activation of the carpal flexors: the [flexor carpi ulnaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexor_carpi_ulnaris_muscle), [flexor carpi radialis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexor_carpi_radialis_muscle), and [palmaris longus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmaris_longus_muscle) (if it is present). Flexion of the wrist during the curl can works these muscles concentrically rather than isometrically. And since they are smaller than the elbow flexors, they therefore fatigue more easily. Fixing that the wrist straight during the lift ensures that the carpal flexors contract isometrically only, and are hence stronger and more resistant to fatigue.

There *is* a third possibility, that the muscles of the forearm are, for whatever reason, just weaker relative to the other muscles in the chain. This can happen if your training is unbalanced, or if your occupation otherwise stresses certain muscles more than others. In such cases, your programme may need to be adjusted to limit the overuse of those muscles.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll try fixing my elbows and making sure my wrists aren't overtly flexing. However, I have a new theory on why this problem is occurring:

Currently I use 6kg dumbbell, but I do 3 sets of 15~20 reps which is a lot more than the  8-10 reps I normally hear about (this may be why my forearms tire out before I can 'work' my biceps).

The reason I do 15~20 reps is because I hardly feel like my biceps are being worked.. I wish I could do 30 to really feel a 'work out' on my biceps, but the forearms tire out before I could do that.

Comment: However, currently, I would need to buy a 10kg dumbbell via amazon which is way too heavy for me and I don't know how long it will take for me to be able to do 8-10 reps with that (my parents don't want to 'waste' buying an 8kg only to have to buy a 10kg later on)

Comment: Is it the 6kg dumbbell's large amount of reps causing my forearm tiredness? would the 8kg (if I can convince my parents) solve it? Or is buying & using a 10kg by doing like 1~2 reps each time going to be fine as well (until a month later when I can do 8-10 reps with a 10kg if that's even possible)?

Comment: Yes, you have identified yet another possibility—that it is being caused by a difference in the endurance characteristics of the different muscle groups. And yes, that could be solved by simply purchasing an intermediate (8-kilogram) dumbbell. However, with adequate work and rest, you should find that the forearms "catch up" with the strength and endurance of the biceps. Indeed, it is common that some part of the chain is significantly weaker or less resistant than the others.

Comment: So going for a 10kg would be too much right (doing like 2~4 reps)? 8kg as an intermediate makes more sense (5~6 reps, etc)?

Would a 10 kg strain my muscles and also not allow me to progress that much... or is rather skipping the 8kg and jumping up to a 10kg totally fine?

Comment: It would normally be a sub-optimal approach to jump to 10 kgs, but you could do it. You would just have to accept that, yes, you would be performing low repetitions, and that that would likely slow your progress.

Comment: Thank you for your time and responses; they made my day. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -2):

You should try to fix your biceps when you are doing this exercise (you can search biceps curl on google, you will find some photos and understand what I mean ). Do it nice and slow, do maximum 4-5 reps for building strength and 8-10 reps for building muscles, good luck.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean by "fix your biceps" I'm just doing a standing bicep curl: (image: https://bit.ly/2XhaqPu).

Comment: Currently I use 6kg dumbbell, but I do 3 sets of 15~20 reps which is a lot more than 8-10 reps (this may be why my forearms tire out before I can 'work' my biceps). 

However, currently, I would need to buy a 10kg dumbbell via amazon which is way too heavy for me and I don't know how long it will take for me to be able to do 8-10 reps with that (my parents don't want to 'waste' buying an 8kg only to have to buy a 10kg later on)

Comment: Is it the 6kg dumbbell's large amount of reps causing my forearm tiredness? would the 8kg (if I can convince my parents) solve it? Or is buying & using a 10kg by doing like 1~2 reps each time going to be fine as well (until a month later when I can do 8-10 reps with a 10kg if that's even possible)?

Comment: **Do you possibly mean "fix your elbows" as the poster below has said?**

Comment: @Rey exactly , that’s what I meant